# Android dialog not displaying data sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, dialog

I am trying to display data from an SQLite database in a dialog.
The data is a list of scores.
All works well until I add a totals line and then it goes real haywire.

This is the source:

```
            DBAdaptor dbAdaptor;
        Cursor scoresCursor;
        Cursor totalsCursor;
        //ScoresDisplayerAdaptor scoresDisplayerAdaptor;  

        dbAdaptor = new DBAdaptor(this);
        dbAdaptor.open();
        scoresCursor = dbAdaptor.getScores();
        totalsCursor = dbAdaptor.getTotalScores();


        startManagingCursor(scoresCursor);
        startManagingCursor(totalsCursor);

        //scoresDisplayerAdaptor = new ScoresDisplayerAdaptor(this,scoresCursor);

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.scores);
        ListView lv = (ListView)dialog.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.lvwScores);
        ((TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvwPlayer1Name)).setText(players[0].playerName);
        ((TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvwPlayer2Name)).setText(players[1].playerName);

        switch (settings.getNumberOfPlayers())
        {
            case 2:
                lv.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.playerscoresrow, scoresCursor, 
                        new String[] {DBAdaptor.KEY_PLAYER1_SCORE,DBAdaptor.KEY_PLAYER2_SCORE}, 
                        new int[]    {R.id.tvwPlayer1Score,       R.id.tvwPlayer2Score }
                ));
                break;

            case 3: 
                ((TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvwPlayer3Name)).setText(players[2].playerName);
                lv.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.playerscoresrow, scoresCursor, 
                        new String[] {DBAdaptor.KEY_PLAYER1_SCORE,DBAdaptor.KEY_PLAYER2_SCORE,
                                      DBAdaptor.KEY_PLAYER3_SCORE}, 
                        new int[]    {R.id.tvwPlayer1Score,       R.id.tvwPlayer2Score, 
                                      R.id.tvwPlayer3Score}
                ));
                break;

            case 4:
                ((TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvwPlayer3Name)).setText(players[2].playerName);
                ((TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvwPlayer4Name)).setText(players[3].playerName);

                lv.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.playerscoresrow, scoresCursor, 
                        new String[] {DBAdaptor.KEY_PLAYER1_SCORE,DBAdaptor.KEY_PLAYER2_SCORE,
                                      DBAdaptor.KEY_PLAYER3_SCORE,DBAdaptor.KEY_PLAYER4_SCORE}, 
                        new int[]    {R.id.tvwPlayer1Score,       R.id.tvwPlayer2Score, 
                                      R.id.tvwPlayer3Score,       R.id.tvwPlayer4Score }
                ));
        }
/*
        lv.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.scores, totalsCursor, 
                new String[] {DBAdaptor.KEY_PLAYER1_TOTAL,DBAdaptor.KEY_PLAYER1_TOTAL,
                              DBAdaptor.KEY_PLAYER1_TOTAL,DBAdaptor.KEY_PLAYER1_TOTAL}, 
                new int[]    {R.id.tvwPlayer1Total,       R.id.tvwPlayer2Total, 
                              R.id.tvwPlayer3Total,       R.id.tvwPlayer4Total }
        ));*/
        dialog.setTitle("Scores");
        Button aButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
        aButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
                askNewHand(); 

            } });
        dialog.show();
        dbAdaptor.close();
```

Where the two cursors are:

```
    public Cursor getScores(long rowId) throws SQLException 
{
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                    KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_PLAYER1_SCORE,
                    KEY_PLAYER2_SCORE,
                    KEY_PLAYER3_SCORE,
                    KEY_PLAYER4_SCORE
                    }, 
                    KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, 
                    null,
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
public Cursor getTotalScores() {
    return db.rawQuery(
        "SELECT 0 as _id, SUM(" + KEY_PLAYER1_SCORE + ") as " + KEY_PLAYER1_TOTAL + ", " +
               "SUM(" + KEY_PLAYER2_SCORE + ") as " + KEY_PLAYER2_TOTAL + ", " +
               "SUM(" + KEY_PLAYER3_SCORE + ") as " + KEY_PLAYER3_TOTAL + ", " +
               "SUM(" + KEY_PLAYER4_SCORE + ") as " + KEY_PLAYER4_TOTAL + " " +
        "FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE,null);
}
```

The main XML looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout 
  android:id="@+id/lloPlayerNames" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:orientation="horizontal">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer1Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="14.5sp"/>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer2Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="14.5sp"/>
  <TextView     
    android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer3Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="14.5sp"/>
  <TextView     
    android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer4Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="14.5sp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<Button android:id="@+id/btnOK"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:text="OK" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 

  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 

   />
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/lloTotalScores" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_above="@id/btnOK">
  <TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer1Total" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer2Total" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer3Total" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer4Total" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="14.5sp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView 
   android:id="@+id/lvwScores" 
   android:layout_below="@id/lloPlayerNames"

   android:layout_above="@id/lloTotalScores"

   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

As long as the lines filling the totals are commented out then the screen displayed is ok:

[image]

However, as soon as I un-comment those lines to display the total I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want a fixed list (row) of players at the top of your view plus a corresponding list (row) of their total scores at the bottom. Then inbetween, you want an expanding list of scores for each hand of a game that has been played. Am I right?

**EDIT:** OK, ignore my suggestion of using / extending HeaderViewListAdapter as ListView supports headers/footers natively and uses HeaderViewListAdapter internally (DOH!!!).

Try the following (not sure the code is 100% correct though)...

Do what you're currently doing to set the player names in the `lloPlayerNames` TextViews. Then adjust your code to set the `lloTotalScores` TextViews to contain the values returned from your `getTotalScores()` query. Then use something like...

```
LinearLayout llHeaderView = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lloPlayerNames);
lv.addHeaderView(llHeaderView);

...

LinearLayout llFooterView = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lloTotalScores);
lv.addFooterView(llFooterView);
```

Then you use `lv.setAdapter()` to put in the results from your `getScores()` query. NOTE: you MUST set the header and footer before calling `setAdapter()`

Hope that helps.

Comment: @theblitz: See my EDIT to my answer

Comment: Do I leave the header and footer in my scores xml or should they be in separate ones? I ask cos I am now getting a ClassCastException on the setAdaptor command.

Comment: @theblitz: Try moving your Button to the very bottom of the XML layout file (but obviously still within the RelatieLayout).

Comment: Still the same. I'll take a shot at it tomorrow and report back.

Comment: @theblitz: I see you found a workaround. I think it should still work with the header/footer although I'd put the header/footer LinearLayouts in a separate layout file and inflate them in code. The main layout file would then just have the ListView and the Button (possibly in a LinearLayout instead of a RelativeLayout). If you're happy with what you've got though, that's great.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your root layout is a RelativeLayout. So, what's happening is your second LinearLayout is covering up the first one.

You can solve this two ways:

- Make your root layout a LinearLayout. This way, the second LinearLayout will be positioned after the first, instead of on top of it.
- Add a "Margin-top" rule of say, 100px, to the 2nd linear layout. This will push it down and expose the 1st layout...

Comment: Problem is that I have to make it a RelativeLayout otherwise the whole thing didn't work.

Comment: Tried converting to Linear but that screwed it up completely.

Comment: @theblitz - Try making the root element a linearLayout with both layout parameters like -  android:layout_height="fill_parent" & android:layout_width="fill_parent".

Answer (score 1):

In the end I solved this by creating a new ListView for my totals under the one for the data and populating it with a new XML that I created.
I don't know if this is the optimum way to go but at least it works.